# PostgreSQL autovacuum ignoring "inactive" tables resulting in "transaction id wraparound"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, autovacuum

I have a PostgreSQL database with a lot of tables (currently 93k) and I'm seeing issues with transaction id age threatening wraparound, because autovacuum is not getting triggered for clean tables that haven't been written to in a long time.

For example, I have a table that I can tell hasn't been written to since '2018-09-19 10:30:43.625069+00' thanks to the only inserts to this table always setting an `updated_at` column (current datetime is '2018-10-04 23:58:25.545881+00'), has `n_dead_tup = 0`, and has `age(relfrozenxid) > 10000000`.

I have `autovacuum_freeze_max_age = 10000000` so this should mean this table will get autovacuumed, but instead I see it get past this point and then autovacuum doesn't get triggered for the table (it's currently at `age(relfrozenxid) > 70000000` and autovacuum still hasn't triggered.

I currently have autovacuum set to be maximally aggressive and yet this is still happening. Here are the autovacuum settings:

```
track_counts = on
autovacuum = on
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 0
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = 10000
autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0
autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = 1
autovacuum_freeze_max_age = 10000000
vacuum_freeze_min_age = 1000000
```

(yes, I realize `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit` doesn't matter because `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay` is `0`)

Currently I'm forced to periodically manually trigger vacuums for these tables to keep things from getting out of hand. This feels like a hack, though.

Is there a way to get autovacuum to vacuum these tables, or equivalently a reason why autovacuum is ignoring these tables?

**ETA**

In case anyone comes here wanting to see my script for dealing with this, here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
while true; do
  sleep 60 #just in case there's nothing sleep so we don't run this too hard; at the start to prevent rapid process bouncing when postgres is offline
  psql -d warehouse -t -c "select nspname || '.' || relname from pg_class join pg_namespace on pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace where age(relfrozenxid) > 100000000 and relfrozenxid != 0 order by age(relfrozenxid) desc;" | sed '/^$/d' | parallel -j10 -q bash -c 'echo -n "autovacuum {} to prevent wraparound: " ; psql -d warehouse -c "vacuum freeze {}"'
  echo -n "vacuum postgres database: "
  psql -d postgres -c "vacuum freeze" #just to be safe
done
```

You'll probably want to up `superuser_reserved_connections` by `10` or whatever number you specify to `parallel` using the `-j` flag to make sure you can still access the database if regular connections are exhausted without shutting this down.

Comment: That shouldn't be happening.  What minor version are you using (`select version()`?  Are there any ERRORs (or other messages) in the server log file that seems relevant to autovac?  Has this been upgraded from previous versions using pg_upgrade, and if so what versions?  Has it had a history of crashes or corruption?  What is the `age(datfrozenxid)` from pg_databases for the relevant database(s)?

Comment: Also, what is `autovacuum_max_workers`, and can you look into pg_stat_activity to see if it is attempting to do autovacuuming?  (Also likely to show up in `top` or `ps` if you run them showing the full command line)

Comment: One can also log all autovacuum activities by setting `log_autovacuum_min_duration` to 0.

Comment: so plenty of autovacuums are running, just not the ones i need to run. i have `autovacuum_max_workers` set to `24` (this is on an i3.metal so I have 72 cores, 512 GB RAM, and over 100k IOPS) and with the above settings I typically see 24 autovacuum processes running at all times.

Comment: version is `PostgreSQL 10.5 (Ubuntu 10.5-1.pgdg16.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit` and I've never run pg_upgrade on this cluster. no crashes or corruption. `age(datfrozenxid)` stays between 100 million and 200 million thanks to my script to aggressively run vacuums on these tables, but without it will grow towards the dreaded 2.1 billion mark (I've not let it go past 1 billion, though, before stopping everything to run `vacuum freeze`).

Comment: @GGordonWorleyIII did you manage to solve this in the end?

Comment: i guess? i haven't seen this behavior since upgrading to postgres 11